# Is it possible to retrieve only a single property from a CSS class?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Example CSS File:

```
.testClass {
color: black;
background: red; }
```

Now in an HTML file, I would like to have something like

```
<span class="testClass:color">Text in black but without red background</span>
```

to only apply the color property of that class.

Is there a way to do this?

The purpose behind it (for people asking themselves "Why the hell would he want that, that's not clean CSS usage!") is that I use jQuery UI themes, and I would like the entire page to fit a theme upon change. As not all kinds of elements (e.g. the color of a link) are covered by those themes, in those cases I would like to "steal" the color property (but not more) of some other CSS class of the jQuery UI theme. If there is another way to do this, of course I'm glad to hear it as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.
But you can override that property as follows

```
<span class="testClass" style="background:none; ">
      Text in black but without red background
 </span>
```

OR

```
.testClass {
color: black;
background: red;
}

.testClassNoBack {
background: none;
}

<span class="testClass testClassNoBack" >
      Text in black but without red background
 </span>
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't thought of that!

Answer (score 1):

It certainly could be done using js and some creativity, but it would take some time with the use of `document.styleSheets` and its respective rules as described [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html). But I wouldnt recommend it, because the rules for the `document.styleSheets` differ from browser to browser. Salil's solution is more cleaner and I would say that the css way is even faster to some extend.

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't. you should create a new class for that case.

Comment: @nabizan - because it can't be? If CSS and HTML doesn't allow it to work, then it can't be done.

Unless you come up with some javascript method, but then I doubt it'd validate anyway.

Comment: @all: guys im just wondering how could any programmer say that something / anything cannot be done ... every problem could be solve, just use your imagination, some creativity and good will ... for example look at realshadows answer